# Update a note in the Notes application using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I try this code, but it removes the title of the note! How to leave a note's title?

```
tell application "Notes"
    tell account "iCloud"
        tell folder "Category"
            set body of note "Test Post" to "reset the body text"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

The name/title of the note is usually the first line in the note.

Get the name of the note, save it temporarily, set the body and reassign the name

```
tell application "Notes"
    tell account "iCloud"
        tell folder "Category"
            tell note "Test Post"
                set tempName to its name
                set body to "reset the body text"
                set its name to tempName
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I forgot the `tell folder` line. Please see the update.

Comment: Throws error receiving notes with title "Test Post"!

Comment: Of course there must be a note with this name in this folder in this account.

Comment: Yes she is! After set body the name of the note is changing! Set the old name is no longer obtained!

Comment: I wrote *usually*. The body of the note is actually HTML text, so just updating the name might not be sufficient.